# Spark not deleting old data in MemSql when Overwrite mode is used

Tags: apache-spark, singlestore

I am running a spark job using overwrite mode. I was expecting that it will delete the data in the table and will insert new data. However it is just appending the data to it .

I was expecting same behavior as when save moce override is used in fileSystem,

```scala
object HiveToMemSQL {
def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val log = Logger.getLogger(HiveToMemSQL.getClass)

    //var options = getOptions()
    //val cmdLineArgs = new CommandLineOptions().validateArguments(args, options)

    //if (cmdLineArgs != null) {

    // Get command line options values
    var query = "select * from default.students"
    // Get destination DB details from command line
    val destHostName ="localhost"
    //val destUserName = cmdLineArgs.getOptionValue("destUserName")
    //val destPassword = cmdLineArgs.getOptionValue("destPassword")
    val destDBName ="tsg"
    val destTable = "ORC_POS_TEST"
    val destPort = 3308
    val destConnInfo = MemSQLConnectionInfo(destHostName, destPort, "root", "", destDBName)

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Hive To MemSQL")
    .config("maxRecordsPerBatch" ,"100")
    .config("spark.memsql.host", destConnInfo.dbHost)
    .config("spark.memsql.port", destConnInfo.dbPort.toString)
    .config("spark.memsql.user", destConnInfo.user)
    .config("spark.memsql.password", destConnInfo.password)
    .config("spark.memsql.defaultDatabase", destConnInfo.dbName)
    //          .config("org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode" , SaveMode.Overwrite.toString())
    .config("spark.memsql.defaultSaveMode"  , "Overwrite")
    .config("maxRecordsPerBatch" ,"100").master("local[*]").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    import spark.sql

    // Queries are expressed in HiveQL
    val sqlDF = spark.sql("select* from tsg.v_pos_krogus_wk_test")
    log.info("Successfully read data from source")
    sqlDF.printSchema()
    sqlDF.printSchema()

    // MemSQL destination DB Master Aggregator, Port, Username and Password
    import spark.implicits._

    // Disabling writing to leaf nodes directly
    var saveConf = SaveToMemSQLConf(spark.memSQLConf,
    params = Map("useKeylessShardingOptimization" -> "false", 
                 "writeToMaster" -> "false" , 
                 "saveMode" -> SaveMode.Overwrite.toString()))

    log.info("Save mode before  :" + saveConf.saveMode )
    saveConf= saveConf.copy(saveMode=SaveMode.Overwrite)
    log.info("Save mode after  :" + saveConf.saveMode )

    val tableIdent = TableIdentifier(destDBName, destTable)
    sqlDF.saveToMemSQL(tableIdent, saveConf)

    log.info("Successfully completed writing to MemSQL DB")
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MemSQL Spark Connector setting will write a REPLACE statement. REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. See https://docs.memsql.com/sql-reference/v6.0/replace/

Comment: is there a way , i can truncate the table before insert like how i can do it using jdbc write format in spark ?